# Does this word exist?

Tags: word-choice

If you want to summarize "I am good in engaging (with) others", meaning "getting them interested and involved", can you say then "I'm an engager"? Or how would you call it, "I am an...". Does the word "engager" exist in English?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you found the word in an English dictionary?

Comment: Please take a second to write a more meaningful title. You are asking about a specific word, so mention that specific word in the title, and not "this word", which applies to every word ever. Specific question titles attract more views, and thus more answers. Nobody clicks on vague titles.

Comment: "Engage" is a verb.  Most active verbs you can turn into nouns by adding "er" (and eliminating excess "e" characters as appropriate).  However, using the word in that fashion would not be idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Engager is in the full OED (Oxford English dictionary) and has been since 1891.

> 1. One who enters into an engagement or agreement; †a surety, guarantor.
>      a. One who engages in an enterprise or occupation.
>      b. One who engages the service of another; an employer.
> 2. One of those who signed or approved of the ‘Engagement’ of 1647.

Comment: This is not the definition that the op proposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

In brainstorming fashion:

> I am good at interacting with others.
>
> I am good at repartee.
>
> I am a good conversationalist.
>
> I am good at motivating people.
>
> I am good at galvanizing people.
>
> I am good at spurring people to get involved.
>
> I am good at actuating people.

Comment: But the question was whether *engager* was a word. I don't think any of your examples say quite the same thing as *I am good at engaging people*, though some may come close. I have no doubt the word *engager* exists, but I doubt I would use it - better *I am good at engaging*, I would say.

Answer (score 0):

You would say "I am an engaging leader."

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all for replying to my message? It has been clarifying.